# Could use some clarity on my first time using std::distance

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a vector variable called 'cache' (which stores strings, but I don't think that's needed info).

I want to find the last occurrence of the variable 'latest', a string of course, in this vector 'cache'. I use std::find. Since I want to find the last occurrence instead of the first, I use reverse iterators, as shown here:

```
find(cache.rbegin(), cache.rend(), latest)
```

That returns as expected. Now, I want to find the distance between the first element of  'cache' and this returned iterator (the spot of the last occurrence of 'latest' in 'cache').

So I try:

```
distance(cache.begin(), find(cache.rbegin(), cache.rend(), latest))
```

Or, more visibly:

```
auto it = find(cache.rbegin(), cache.rend(), latest)

distance(cache.begin(), it)
```

But I get "No matching function for call to 'distance'".

I know this is simple but I've been searching for about an hour so I came here. Any info would be appreciated. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you `#include <iterator>` and qualify with the right namespace `std::distance`?

Comment: Note that you would be iterate through the entire vector with your method. If you knew the size of "cache" already, then it could be better if you also do a counting while trying to find the target, and the do subtraction from the size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to compute the distance between a reverse iterator and a regular iterator. The types of the two arguments to `std::distance` must be the same. Try this instead:

```
size_t dist_from_begin =
    std::distance(find(cache.rbegin(), cache.rend(), latest), cache.rend());
```

Comment: @JerryCoffin No it doesn't. It gives the distance from `rend`, which is the beginning :)

Comment: it does indeed give the right answer, thanks and thanks to Jerry Coffin as well!!

Comment: I have a feeling this might be end up off by one, but I guess that's basically what @JerryCoffin commented earlier

Answer (score 2):

Right now, you're trying to call `distance` with one forward iterator and one reverse iterator--but it expects to deal with two iterators of the same type.

To make it work, you need to get the "base" of the reverse iterator, which will be a forward iterator to the same location.

```
auto it = find(cache.rbegin(), cache.rend(), latest)

distance(cache.begin(), it.base());
```

You could also use:

```
distance(cache.rbegin(), it);
```

...but that will give you the distance from the end to the item you found, rather than the distance from the beginning, so it'll compile, but give the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing different iterator types here. `it` is a reverse iterator and `cache.begin()` returns a normal iterator, `distance` doesn't like that.